# Calling instance method in init

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the following error:

> get_fields_labels() got an unexpected keyword argument 'get_query_builder'

I have this call in my **init** method:

```
def __init__(self, address, api_key, mysql_engine):

    self.fields = self.get_fields_labels(get_query_builder=True)
```

I moved the get_fields_labels() to a different method that I call after an object is initialized and then the error goes away. Is there a concept I'm not getting? It seems I can't call methods with arguments during the creation of the object?

Comment: Show us the definition of the `get_fields_labels()` method; that's where the problem is...

Comment: @j-oh what is the signature (parameters expected) for function `get_fields_labels`? Does it take a positional argument `get_query_builder`? Is `get_query_builder` a class method or static method outside the class?

Comment: signature is:

def get_fields_labels(self, run_query_builder=False, select_labels=None):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that in your signature your variable is `run_query_builder`, but you call it with `get_query_builder`. You need to either change your call to:

```
self.fields = self.get_fields_labels(run_query_builder=True)
```

Or your signature to:

```
def get_fields_labels(self, get_query_builder=False, select_labels=None):
```